# API authentication using timestamp : What to do when the client's time setting is changed?

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication

I am implementing an REST API authentication system.

I am basically using the method explained in this site:

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Basically it uses the request body to create a hash, sends it to the server along with the actual request, the server recreates and compares it, and what not...

I won't bother explaining the details. The important part is that **I am using a timestamp** in order to prevent "replay attacks".

Quoting from the site, it explains:

> Compare the current server’s timestamp to the timestamp the client sent. Make sure the difference between the two timestamps it within an acceptable time limit (5-15mins maybe) to hinder replay attacks.

The problem I am facing now is that **if the client's clock setting is modified, it may cause unexpected API authentication failures, since the timestamp varies between the client and the server**.

Is there no way around this? Do I have to give up on using the timestamp?

I would highly appreciate it if anyone can help me out with a solution for this timestamp problem, or with any other way which I can prevent replay attacks.

**Note:** I am aware that issuing a nonce to the client is an excellent way to prevent "replay attacks", but I want to make that my last resort, since the implementation cost of creating a nonce-issuing-API and the backend to manage the nonce is too large.

Comment: If the client's clock setting is modified frankly there will indeed be authentication failures and nobody can help except client has to investigate and rechange the settings.  There are few things to really stop worrying about.  Also 5-15mins is too large a acceptable limit.  It should be +-60 seconds.  Don't stop your idea of sending timestamp just for a irresponsible client.  Your question is very good though.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, do you solve it ? Thank  you

Comment: Dead link :/ I think this is the same article though: http://acaasia.blogspot.com/2013/04/designing-secure-rest-web-api-without.html

Answer (score 2):

When comparing the server's time stamp with the client sent timestamp, it does not have to be THE client timestamp, but the previuously timestamp sent by the server to the client.
You can never rely on client's own timestamp as it could be anything or it could be in the other side of the world.

When the client connects to the server the first time, the server can reply a timestamp from itself and stored on the client, the next time the client must send the last timestamp received.

Comment: Thanks! Receiving a timestamp from the server to the client would in fact be the same idea as receiving a `nonce` from the server. I agree that it is a very promising solution. But, to make that work, I need to go and fetch a new timestamp EVERY time I want to make an API request. I really do not want to receive have an extra HTTP request for every single API request I make...  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You don't need any extra HTTP request. On every request of the client the server return along with your data a timestamp. The client store this timestamp and the next time you make a request append this info as an additional param.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your timestamp to be UTC time as the updated article indicates.

Comment: Thanks. As I have commented on the other person : I presume I am getting the "seconds since epoch". But wouldn't  that value change if the client (e.g. an iPhone) changes their device's clock setting. That is what is actually happening now. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

- [Store your times as UTC, which is the number of seconds since the unix epoch.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- Display your time fields with time and date formatting to reflect a user's timezone

Comment: Thanks. I presume I am getting the "seconds since epoch". But wouldn't  that value change if the client (e.g. an iPhone) changes their device's clock setting. That is what is actually happening now. Is my understanding right?